# looking for a diffeomorphism (not C1)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ diffeomorphism with $f(B[0,1])\subset B[0,1]$ and $| \det f^{\prime}(x) |<1/2$ for all $x\in B[0,1]$ then for every continuous function $h\colon B[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \int_{f^n(B[0,1])}h(x)dx =0$$

The statement works when $ f $ is a diffeomorphism of class $C^1$. Wherefore seek some diffeomorphism (not C1) to serve as counterexample, but I can not think of any, exist? or question the way it is stated can be proved?

thanks for the help

Comment: What is $B[0,1]$?

Comment: $B[0,1]$ is the unit ball closed in $R^n$

Comment: It is an interesting question but can you explain why do you assume only differentiability and nothing else? In such low regularity settings one typically assumes not differentiability but some Sibolev space condition, which means diff a.e. plus sume integrability condition on derivatives.

Comment: good problem statement has only differentiability, maybe there counterexample for this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is **no** counter-example, and we only need to assume that $h$ is integrable on $B[0,1]$.

In fact, there is a change-of-variables formula for injective differentiable maps as follows.

> **Proposition:** Let $U\subset \Bbb R^n$ be a non-empty open set, and let $T:U\to \Bbb R^n$ be differentiable and injective. Then for every measurable function $g:\Bbb R^n\to [0,+\infty)$, 
>   $$\int_{T(U)} g~dm=\int_U (g\circ T)\cdot |\det T'|~dm,\tag{1}$$ where $m$ denotes the
>   Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$.

The proposition above can be essentially found, for example, in Theorem 7.26 of [Walter Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, Third Edition](http://ruangbacafmipa.staff.ub.ac.id/files/2012/02/Real-and-Complex-Analysis-by-Walter-Rudin.pdf).

As a direct corollary of the proposition above, if $K\subset U$ is some compact set and $g$ is the indicator function of $T(K)$, then applying $(1)$ to $g$ yields
$$m(T(K))=\int_K|\det T'|~dm.\tag{2}$$

In our situation, $U=\Bbb R^n$ and for every $k\ge 1$, $T=f^k$ is differentiable and injective on $U$. Moreover, for $K=B[0,1]$, we know that $|\det T'|\le \frac{1}{2^k}$ on $K$. Then from $(2)$ we know that 
$$m\big(f^k(B[0,1])\big)\le \frac{1}{2^k}m\big(B[0,1]\big),\  \forall k\ge 1\Longrightarrow \lim_{k\to \infty}m\big(f^k(B[0,1])\big)=0.\tag{3}$$ 
Due to $(3)$ and the fact $f^k(B[0,1])\subset B[0,1]$ for every $k\ge 1$, if $h:B[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ is integrable, 
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{f^k(B[0,1])} h~dm=0.$$

Comment: this is a (good) demonstration but it doesn't reply to the question. Why isn't there any counter example ?

Comment: @Thomas: I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: the interesting part in "a counterexample" would be with f not a diffeomorphism, or relaxing the < 1/2

Comment: @Thomas: Please read this sentence in the original question: "Wherefore seek some diffeomorphism (not C1) to serve as counterexample"

Comment: @Giraffe: Thanks for replying, I knew this theorem so generic. In class we use the change of variable theorem given in sipivak (calculation varieties) where $T$ is injective and class $C^{1}$ (theorem 3-13). But these theorems are equivalent?, Because in the spivak is Jordan-measurable sets (with volume defined) but in the measurable sets Rudin dry  http://dibene.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/spivak-calculo-en-variedades.pdf

Comment: @Giraffe yes I see that but when "there is no counterexample" it is usually a bad sign. It is cool to know that a theorem works and that there is a counterexample for any condition that you remove. I was just trying to reformulate the question to make this happen :)

Comment: @helmonio: You are welcome. The theorem I cited in Rudin's book has much weaker assumption than theorem 3-13 in Spivak's book, because it doesn't assume $T$ is of $C^1$, i.e. the of partial derivatives of $T$ may not be continuous. To prove such a theorem we have to introduce Lebesgue measurable sets, which are much general than Jordan measurable sets.

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you for your explanation. Anyway, I think you understand what I mean now. If there is another feedback about the confusion caused by the first sentence in my answer, I will consider to edit my answer.

Comment: @Giraffe: thank you very much

Comment: @helmonio: You are welcome. I am not clear about your background on Lebesgue's theory. If you are quite unfamiliar with it, I am afraid you should only accept the statement of the theorem I cited rather than try to understand its proof at this moment; otherwise, please feel free to ask me if there is anything unclear to you.